# Scandinavian letters (such as Ä, Ö and Å) keyboard exist in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

i want to use Scandinavian letters (such as Ä, Ö and Å) keyboard in my application. Do you guys any idea about it. Thanks

Comment: Thats a user setting, the user him/herself must install the preferred keyboard settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is based on the users own language settings at the phone level.

[Check this out](http://iphone.appstorm.net/how-to/change-your-keyboard-or-display-language-in-ios/)

Answer (score 3):

This is a user specific setting.  If the user has set their iPhone's keyboard to a Scandinavian keyboard, then that is what will be displayed in your app.

Also, if you press and hold any letter in the normal iPhone keyboard, after a couple seconds, it will pop-up all "special" forms of the given character, including umlauts and the like.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe their is a specific keyboard for Scandinavian letters but the standard keyboard allows for these special characters by holding the key down for a couple seconds.